# colMeans failing within for loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I've been working on scraping data from the web and manipulating it in R, but I'm having some trouble when I begin to include the dreaded for loop.  I am working with some arbitrary sport statistics, with the idea being that I can calculate the per game average for various stats for each player.

Each of these pieces works outside of the loop, but falls apart inside.  Ideally, my code will do three things:

1) Scraping the data.  I have a list of player names "names" (by row), and the unique piece of the url for each player in column 2.  The website has a table named "stats" on each page, which is nice of them.

```
library(XML)
statMean <- matrix(ncol = 8, nrow = 20)

for(h in 1:20){
   webname <- names[h,2]
   vurl    <- paste("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/", 
                    webname, "/gamelog/2015")
   tables  <- readHTMLTable(vurl)
   t1      <- tables$stats
```

2) Pick the columns I want and turn the values into numeric values.

```
   temp     <- t1[, c(9,10,12,13,14,15,17)]
   temp     <- sapply(temp, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

3) Calculate the mean of each column, bind the unique player name to the column means, and rbind that vector to a full table.

```
   statMean <- rbind(statMean, c(webname, colMeans(temp)))
```

When I run through these steps outside of the Loop, it seems to work ... when I run the loop I inevitably get:

*Error in colMeans(temp) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions*

I've looked at a number of For Loop questions on this site, and my code looks a lot different than how it started.  Unfortunately, each time I try something new, I end up with a version of the above error.

Any help would be fantastic.  Thanks.

Comment: Providing the `names` data would help to simulate your error. I notice the asignment to vurl should probably use paste0 instead of paste, which by default adds a space as a separator. Code:

`paste0("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/", 
                    webname, "/gamelog/2015")`

Comment: Yes, the spaces in vurl is causing problems.  As currently written you are appending onto statmean,  I believe  you want this instead: statMean[h] <- c(webname, colMeans(temp)).